# How to check if sheet A and B are literally the same sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm trying to optimize my sheets onEdit function by initially checking if the modified cells are even in the right sheet like this:

```
var spreadsheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("ONE")
var spreadsheet2 =  ss.getSheetByName("TWO")

function onEdit(e) {

  let range = e.range
  
  Logger.log("Starting onEdit")

  Logger.log("Range: " + range.getSheet().getSheetId().toString())
  Logger.log("spreadsheet1: " + spreadsheet1.getSheetId().toString())
  Logger.log("spreadsheet2: " + spreadsheet1.getSheetId().toString())

  Logger.log("Is spreadsheet1 :" + range.getSheet().getSheetId() == spreadsheet1.getSheetId())
  Logger.log("Is spreadsheet2:" + range.getSheet().getSheetId() == spreadsheet2.getSheetId())
  
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetId() == spreadsheet1.getSheetId() ||
      range.getSheet().getSheetId() == spreadsheet2.getSheetId())
  {
    do stuff
  }
```

The logs look like this:

```
Oct 12, 2021, 2:12:54 PM    Info    Starting onEdit
Oct 12, 2021, 2:12:54 PM    Info    Range: 78085800
Oct 12, 2021, 2:12:54 PM    Info    spreadsheet1: 78085800
Oct 12, 2021, 2:12:54 PM    Info    spreadsheet2: 514624715
Oct 12, 2021, 2:12:54 PM    Info    Is spreadhseet1: false
Oct 12, 2021, 2:12:54 PM    Info    Is spreadsheet2: false
```

One of the two conditions should return true and the if should be evaluated as true but for some reason it doesn't work!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `sheet A and B are literally the same sheet` and `checking if the modified cells are even in the right sheet like this`. In your situation, do you want to confirm the cell values? Do you want to check the formulas? Do you want to check the cell colors and font colors? Do you want to check other properties?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to get their IDs and compare those

Comment: Are you looking for something like `e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "ONE" || e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "TWO"`?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Yes exactly! Though I don't find any mention of any sort of ID anywhere.

Comment: @Tanaike I want to check if `range.getSheet()` and `spreadsheet1` are the same sheet. As @DmitryKostyuk I want to get their 'IDs' and compare then to see if they're exactly the same sheet.

Comment: Well, you have [`getSheetId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid) :)

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Still can't get `range.getSheet().getSheetId() == spreadsheet1.getSheetId()` to work. Returns false always.
I took the  outputs of `x.getSheet().getSheetId().toString()` to logs and it clearly shows there should be a match but the comparison always returns false :(

Comment: there is no `getSheet()` method. update your question with your new code, you really need to make it easy for people to help you :)

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk
Do you mean such a method doesn't exist?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk I've updated the question with more code and explanation!

Comment: we don't know what `shelve_ss` and `collect_ss` are, maybe they should be false, there is now way of telling from your question. what is you need is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is not reproducible

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Sorry they were supposed to be spreadsheet1 and spreadsheet2!

Comment: Just in case. Trigger `onEdit()` can not read another spreadsheets. It can read only sheets inside current spreadsheet.

Comment: Log `range.getSheet().getSheetId()`

Comment: Just for clarification, they're of `type`: `sheet`s(tabs) and not `spreadsheet`s(files).

Comment: @YuriKhristich They're definitely in the same spreadsheet (file)!

Comment: @TheMaster
They log as 
`Range: 7.80858E7`
`spreadsheet1: 7.80858E7`
and `spreadsheet2: 5.14624715E8`

Comment: Try `Logger.log("Diff" + range.getSheet().getSheetId()-spreadsheet1.getSheetId())`

Comment: @TheMaster The difference logs as `NaN`

Comment: Can you check `typeof`? `console.log(typeof range.getSheetId())` and type of ``spreadsheet1.getSheetId()``?

Comment: @TheMaster Both are of type `number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your loggers. Currently, it's adding two strings together and comparing them to a third. So what's being compared looks something like this:

```
"Is spreadsheet1 :78085800" == "78085800"
```

This is obviously false, so all that's needed is to use parentheses to change the order of operations. Try updating the loggers to the following:

```
Logger.log("Is spreadsheet1: " + (range.getSheet().getSheetId() == spreadsheet1.getSheetId()))
Logger.log("Is spreadsheet2: " + (range.getSheet().getSheetId() == spreadsheet2.getSheetId()))
```

Comment: It's always the little things isn't it!